# Regex to reject only nonalphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, r

If the keyword to be checked is **other**. It should not be preceded or followed by alphanumeric character.

spaces are allowed, \n allowed, Special characters allowed.

Not allowed - "AOther9", "noTHERX"

Allowed - "other", "\nother" , " other ", "$other/"

```
grepl(paste("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","other","[^a-zA-Z0-9]",sep=""),String1 , ignore.case = TRUE)
```

The above regex works well for all cases other than “check” - when check is preceded and followed by nothing.

Comment: `grepl(paste("(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])","other","(?![a-zA-Z0-9])",sep=""),String1 , ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a PCRE regex with lookarounds:

```
grepl(paste("(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])","other","(?![a-zA-Z0-9])",sep=""), String1, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)
             ^^^^           ^           ^^^           ^                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

The negative lookarounds will not *consume* the non-alphanumeric characters, they do not require those characters to actually be present in the string.

You can read [more about lookarounds here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, with this solution, you are not limited to strings with just your keywords enclosed with non-alphanumerics, as in the other answer. You will match them anywhere in the longer string.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `*` quantifier to the inverted ranges, and start `^` and end `$` of line anchors:

```
String1 <- c("AOther9", "noTHERX", "other", "\nother", " other ", "$other/")

grep('^[^a-z0-9]*other[^a-z0-9]*$', String1, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "other"   "\nother" " other " "$other/"
```